# Laravel website is target by bots on AWS, how to prevent this?

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

In Laravel there is Telescope, where you easily can monitor requests. I have an issue that I get spammed a lot by (probably) scrapers. And of course they wanna scan for Wordpress-related information.

[image: Telescope]

I have my website hosted via Laravel Vapor, so via AWS.. and every requests costs money. Is there a way to prevent WP-related scans?

Preferably a solution without WAF, so I can reduce costs on that too and use the same solution also on non-AWS-hosted sites.

Comment: You can configure a rate limiter or bot controls https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/environments.html#firewall but they came with a price https://calculator.aws/#/createCalculator/WAF

Comment: Oh sorry, had to mention that I use Gateway API 2 (to lower costs) and that doesn't work with their Firewall option.

Comment: Idk much about the AWS side, but do you have access to apache/nginx config? htaccess? If so I can provide you with rules to prevent (deny) those kind of requests for WP.

Comment: @Mtxz That is not a solution I was looking for; really need it ór codebase ór aws related

Comment: Well the thing is, using htaccess restrictions can handle (deny) most of those cases at zero costs. An AWS solution would be custom WP rules on the CloudFront level. You also could set up ModSecurity with AWS WAF but those will cost I guess. htaccess rules can deny access to "unwanted access" files and paths. For non-aws WP, I use custom nginx rules (deny), headers (CSP), rate-limit, modsecurity and fail2ban.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to fulfill this specific requirement is by using an external CDN, with explicit rules that do not forward (or timeout) failing requests. I have reasonably good  experience with Cloudflare, but certainly other CDNs out there offer comparable functionality.
I would abstain from using AWS CDN.

Comment: How so? You want a service to filter out Wordpress scans. That can’t be natively done in Laravel in a reliable manner - eg. without blocking IPs. So I really think it is a viable solution.